# Nested sum in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

I have a doubt how can I add the numbers of list including the ones that are on a nested list, for example:

```
test:nestedSum([1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7]).
⇒ 28
```

So far I got this:

```
nestedSum(L) -> nestedSum(L, 0).

nestedSum([H|T], Acc) -> 
nestedSum(T, H + Acc); 

 nestedSum([], Acc) ->
Acc.
```

which only works:

```
test:nestedSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]). 
⇒ 28
```

but it does not sum the numbers that are in the nested sum, How can I do it?

Comment: Not really worth an answer: `lists:sum(lists:flatten(L))`. Check out the [lists module documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html). If you want some more insight into how this would work manually and various tree-walking methods we can all jump on a much more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add one clause to the `nestedSum/2` function for the case when the head of the list is a list:

```
% Add this before the two existing clauses.
nestedSum([H|T], Acc) when is_list(H) ->
  nestedSum(T, nestedSum(H) + Acc);
```

With this, your function can now handle any nested list:

```
1> a:nestedSum([1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7]).
28
2> a:nestedSum([1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, [8, [[[9, [[[[[[10]]]]]]]]]]]).
55
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [lists:flatten](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1%22lists:flatten):

```
nestedSum(L) -> nestedSum(lists:flatten(L), 0).
.
.
```

Reducing a list is often a one-liner:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X,Sum) -> X + Sum end, 0, lists:flatten([1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7])).
```

Comment: Really useful. with flatten is easier.